# Spring boot, get Docker exposed port for eureka registration

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a simple Eureka server  that is pretty much the source from: https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

I have the spring client successfully registering with eureka, and also was able to get the docker image of the client, to register with eureka as well. However, what I want to do is be able to assign docker random port (ephemeral port range) by doing:

```
docker run -p 8080 MY_IMAGE
```

I see that I can go to the resful app (eureka client) via the ephemeral port docker assigns...however, in Eureka registration, the port assigned is 8080, due to the spring configs.

application.yaml:

```
server:
  port: 8080
```

I know I can create a custom eureka config to overwrite the default by doing something like this:

```
 @Bean
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig() {
        EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
        config.setPreferIpAddress(true);
        config.setNonSecurePort(8085); //or any port i want
        return config;
    }
```

but my question is....how can i get the docker exposed port (ephemeral port) in my app so that i can pass it on to eureka?

Comment: Does docker make the ephemeral port available as an environment variable?

Comment: Is eureka server running in Docker as well?

Comment: @spencergibb im not sure...havent been able to find the answer to that

Comment: @yamenk it can be, but obviously it will be in another instance.  so any communication between the 2 must go through normal channels.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3778 or at https://github.com/bitsofinfo/docker-discovery-registrator-consul

Answer (score 2):

I’m currently working on the same issue. My case is little bit more difficult, because I am going to use  -- scale option to run as many running containers as I need, but it is still relevant to your question. After day long research I found that the best way to obtain ephemeral port is to call native docker API  and ask docker for real port number. My code is:

```
@Value("${docker.uri.template}")
private String dockerUriTemplate;
@Value("${docker.protocol}")
String dockerProtocol;
@Value("${docker.host}")
String dockerHost;
@Value("${docker.port}")
String dockerPort;
@Value("${server.port}")
String springServerPort;
// -------
@Bean
@Autowired
public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils) {
    Integer hostPort = 0;

    String containerHostName = getHostname();
    String dockerUri = String.format(dockerUriTemplate, dockerProtocol, dockerHost, dockerPort, containerHostName);

    DockerNetworkSettings networkSettings = new RestTemplate().getForObject(
            dockerUri, DockerNetworkSettings.class);
    hostPort = Integer.parseInt(networkSettings.getNetworkSettings().getPorts().get(springServerPort.concat("/tcp")).get(0).get("HostPort"));

    EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
    config.setNonSecurePort(hostPort);
    config.setHostname(dockerHost);
    config.getMetadataMap().put("instanceId", getHostname());
    return config;
}
```

DockerNetworkSettings class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Proudly created by dmaslov on 01/02/2018.
*/

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonAutoDetect
public class DockerNetworkSettings implements Serializable {
private long id;
@JsonProperty("NetworkSettings")
private NetworkSettings NetworkSettings;

public DockerNetworkSettings.NetworkSettings getNetworkSettings() {
    return NetworkSettings;
}

public void setNetworkSettings(DockerNetworkSettings.NetworkSettings networkSettings) {
    NetworkSettings = networkSettings;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonAutoDetect
public class NetworkSettings {
    @JsonProperty("Ports")
    private LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>> ports;

    public LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>> getPorts() {
        return ports;
    }

    public void setPorts(LinkedHashMap ports) {
        this.ports = ports;
    }
}
}
```

Application settings are:

```
docker:
 uri:
  template: "%s://%s:%s/containers/%s/json"
 protocol: http
 host: docker8978
 port: 2376
```

I hope it will help somebody

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18684637)

Comment: Although I do not completely agree with @MattCremeens , this answer could use some enhancing to improve its quality.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully assigned random port for my eureka clients as below example.

My microservice client docker file content is,

```
   FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
LABEL maintainer="tharanga.w@archisoftglobal.com"
VOLUME /tmp
ENV SERVER_PORT 0
EXPOSE ${SERVER_PORT}
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app.jar", "$@"]
```

docker run command is,

```
sudo docker run  -e spring.profiles.active="dev"  -e SERVER_PORT=0 --name archisoft-common-usermanger archisoft-common-usermanger
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the port as an enviroment property:

```
docker run -p 8085:8085 MY_IMAGE -e EUREKA_PORT=8085
```

Then in your application.yml

```
eureka:
  instance:
     hostname: ${APPLICATION_DOMAIN}
     nonSecurePort: ${EUREKA_PORT:8780}
```

This will cause your app to look for the environment varible that is passed to the container or use the fallback port.

Of course you can also inject the value from the application.yml with @Value into you bean to set the port.

Comment: i dont think that would work. since `docker run -p ARG` means ARG is the port you want exposed, not the ephemeral port you are using.

i.e you would have to know 8085 a head of time, at which point its pointless any way.


your command:

`docker run -p 8085 MY_IMAGE -e EUREKA_PORT=8085`

would expose a random port in docker ephemeral range (32K-61K port range) to port 8085 inside container.

Comment: that wont work..if i Know i am going to use 8085 as the docker exposed port, why would i need to pass it as an env var? i can pass that 8085 in my self.

the point was for docker to use its ephemeral ports